# Modifying gazebo_ros_pkgs to build a custom version of Gazebo

Tags: ros, gazebo, gazebo-ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hei guys,
I am not sure where to modify  **gazebo_ros_pkgs** in order to have my modified version of Gazebo built.
As far as I got I see that there is a file  [gazebo_ros_pkgs/gazebo_dev/cmake/gazebo_dev-extras.cmake](https://github.com/ros-simulation/gazebo_ros_pkgs/blob/kinetic-devel/gazebo_dev/cmake/gazebo_dev-extras.cmake) that uses some environment variables in order to add the source files.

```
# The following lines will tell catkin to add the Gazebo directories and libraries to the
# respective catkin_* cmake variables.
set(gazebo_dev_INCLUDE_DIRS ${GAZEBO_INCLUDE_DIRS})
set(gazebo_dev_LIBRARY_DIRS ${GAZEBO_LIBRARY_DIRS})
set(gazebo_dev_LIBRARIES ${GAZEBO_LIBRARIES})
```

Is that it? If so do I just need to set those up, dowload gazebo_ros_pkgs and then build the workspace?

Tnx

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/265618/modifying--gazebo_ros_pkgs-to-build-a-custom-version-of-gazebo/) by [SorinV](https://answers.ros.org/users/30485/sorinv/) on ROS Answers with karma: 106 on 2017-07-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I managed to use a second version of Gazebo that I manually installed following the [instructions](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=install_from_source) and then adding the path to the installed library to the  `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable. The added path was `/usr/local/lib` like so: `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/lical/lib` from my .bashrc file or locally in the console. If there are any problems download also `gazebo_ros_pkgs` and compile it from a workspace. That seems to fix my problems.

---

Originally posted by [SorinV](https://answers.ros.org/users/30485/sorinv/) with karma: 106 on 2017-07-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0